# MongooseJS Unique combination Index

Tags: express, mongoose, mocha.js

My schema is:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  sku: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    index: true,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  client_id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client',
    index: true,
    required: true
  }
}, {versionKey: false, autoIndex: false});

ItemSchema.index({sku: 1, client_id: 1}, {unique: true});
```

I want sku's to be unique per client_id. So I assume that index will do the trick. I'm running `mocha` unit tests and the test is:

```
  it('should fail if the sku is not unique per client', function(done) {
    var secondItem = validItem;
    return validItem.save(function(err) {
      should.not.exist(err);
      return secondItem.save(function(err) {
        should.exist(err);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

with the logic that saving the second item (same `sku` and same `client_id`) should result in an error. However, I get no error:

```
  1) <Unit Test> Model Item: Method Save should fail if the sku is not unique per client:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected null to exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try this? var secondItem = JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify(validItem)); My guess would be your original reference is getting invalidated after `validItem.save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is failing because you're not saving two documents to the database with the same `sku` and `client_id`, you're saving the *same* document to the database twice.

Try creating a new document and copying the `sku` and`client_id` from the valid item.

```
it('should fail if the sku is not unique per client', function(done) {
  var secondItem = new Item({
     sku: validItem.sku,
     client_id: validItem.client_id,
     description: 'Put whatever you want here'
  });
  return validItem.save(function(err) {
    should.not.exist(err);
    return secondItem.save(function(err) {
      should.exist(err);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Still getting an error:
     `Uncaught AssertionError: expected { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: my-test.items.$client_id_1_sku_1  dup key: { : ObjectId('52f80e8643bb1a0000ebfd5c'), : "ABC123" }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: my-test.items.$client_id_1_sku_1  dup key: { : ObjectId(\'52f80e8643bb1a0000ebfd5c\'), : "ABC123" }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 443,
  ok: 1 } to not exist`